# Different style for each UL in Opencart Category Module

Tags: css, categories, opencart

I have the following structure of categories in my Opencart

```
<ul>
<li class="bu">
    <a href="http://brandoutlet.lv/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205" class="active">PARENT 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_66"> CHILD 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_66_230"> - GRANDCHILD 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_66_229"> - GRANDCHILD 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_66_228"> - GRANDCHILD 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_67" class="active"> CHILD 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_67_231"> - GRANDCHILD 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_67_217"> - GRANDCHILD 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_67_216"> - GRANDCHILD 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=205_67_215"> - GRANDCHILD 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li class="bu">
    <a href="/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=206"> PARENT 2</a>
//....ETC
```

How can I give Parent, Child and Grandchild different styling (color, weight, decoration)?

I was trying to make it work with JS searching for UL and applying class depending on position, but result is messy and incorrect..

Any ideas? Thanks!

The view file:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if($category['children']) { ?>
        <li class="bu">
        <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="onit" >
        <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active" ><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
        <li class="onit" >
          <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active">  <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>">  <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
          <?php } ?>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search and modify the php file that generates this form. Than complete the code with some css classes.

---

**Answer for edited question:**
If you watch the href you can see that the path part has the same number of variables in the same generation:

- Parent: path=205
- Child: path=205_66
- Grandchild: path=205_66_230

You could get this part of the text, and depending on the variable number do the formating. So condition would look like this:

```
if(count(explode("_",strstr($child['href'],"path=")))==1)
   //Do the formating for parent.
```

- Use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to delete before the `path=` part. You can leave out this if there aren't '_' characters before `path=`.
- With [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) you can split the string to an array with the '_' character.
- Than [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) will count the elements of the array.

Compare with 1 for parents, 2 for childs and with 3 for grandchilds.
Otherway I assume by rewriting the code there should be a better way to reach this goal.

Comment: It dynamically creates <ul> and links depending on category-child depth.

Comment: Thanks, that was my idea, but seems to be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could maybe do it like this:

```
ul li {
 color:red;
}

ul li > ul li {
 color:blue;
}

ul li > ul li > ul li {
 color:green;
}
```